# Key inputs using KeyWait are sent out of order

Tags: autohotkey

I am trying to implement Autoshift with AHK

Script waits for key release and when certain time elapses the Hotkey sends a shifted character.

The problem is that when I type keys very fast inputs are swapped:

I type ab - output is ba
I type ba - output is ab

Is there any way to "flush" previous hotkey in waiting state or any way to achieve ordered Keys when using KeyWait?

script:

```
PushDuration := 250

$a::
    time := A_TickCount
    KeyWait, a
    var := A_TickCount - time
    if(var < PushDuration)
      SendEvent, a
    else 
      SendEvent, A
  return

$b::
    time := A_TickCount
    KeyWait, b
    var := A_TickCount - time
    if(var < PushDuration)
      SendEvent, b
    else 
      SendEvent, B
  return
```

Answer (score 0):

You may (or may not) have better luck using separate 'up' hotkeys to handle the key-up events and get rid of the KeyWait calls.

You can also use A_ThisHotkey in conjunction with defining a single (generic) function for a bunch of keys and send a shifted version for whichever key triggered the function call. And/or, I believe the latest versions of AutoHotkey have a generic way to capture inputs without having to have a hotkey definition for each letter.